# how can i reduce the following code by using any loop

Tags: matlab

```
num2 = xlsread('CANCER.xls','C2:C102')
[IDX,C1] = kmeans(num2,2)
num3 = xlsread('CANCER.xls','C103:C203')
[IDX,C2] = kmeans(num3,2)
num4 = xlsread('CANCER.xls','C304:C404')
[IDX,C3] = kmeans(num4,2)
num5 = xlsread('CANCER.xls','C405:C505')
[IDX,C4] = kmeans(num5,2)
num6 = xlsread('CANCER.xls','C506:C606')
[IDX,C5] = kmeans(num6,2)
num7 = xlsread('CANCER.xls','C607:C707')
[IDX,C6] = kmeans(num7,2)
num8 = xlsread('CANCER.xls','C708:C808')
[IDX,C7] = kmeans(num8,2)
num9 = xlsread('CANCER.xls','C809:C909')
[IDX,C8] = kmeans(num9,2)
num10 = xlsread('CANCER.xls','C1000:C1099')
[IDX,C9] = kmeans(num10,2)
num11= xlsread('CANCER.xls','C1100:C1199')
[IDX,C10] = kmeans(num11,2)
num12= xlsread('CANCER.xls','C1200:C1299')
[IDX,C11] = kmeans(num12,2)
num13= xlsread('CANCER.xls','C1300:C1399')
[IDX,C12] = kmeans(num13,2)
num14= xlsread('CANCER.xls','C1400:C1499')
[IDX,C13] = kmeans(num14,2)
kmns=[C1;C2;C3;C4;C5;C6;C7;C8;C9;C10;C11;C12;C13;C14]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
%%// Start and stop row numbers
start_ind = [2 103 304 405 506 607 708 809 1000 :100: 1400];
stop_ind = [start_ind(1:8)+100  start_ind(9:end) + 99];

data = xlsread('CANCER.xls'); %%// Read data in one-go
C = zeros(2,numel(start_ind)); %%// Place holder for C values 
for k1 = 1:numel(start_ind)
    num = data(start_ind(k1):stop_ind(k1),3); %%// Data for the specified range 
    [IDX,C(:,k1)] = kmeans(num,2); %%// Do the calculations
end
kmns = reshape(C,[],1); %%// Final result
```